# Cannot browse Horizon "openstack-dashboard"

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I install `maas` > `juju` > `OpenStack` with co-located services.

The "openstack-dashboard" charm is installed on the same node with "keystone".

All the units are up with no errors, and this is the output of [juju stat](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6621939/)

I also mapped all the hosts names at `/etc/hosts`.

Yet the `http://openstack-dashboard/horizon` 500 Internal service error`.

I got the Apache2 [error.log](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6622006) and it's filled with python exceptions which "as a sysadmin" I cannot interpret.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? If you can't resolve the hostname, you might need to [configure DNS](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/configure.html#client-side-dns-configuration); otherwise, please add more detail about what you're expecting but not getting.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: According to status output, shouldn't that be `http://rm-mas-04.rmgs.labs/horizon`?

Comment: Yes it should. yet it's not there.
I tried deploying the dashboard to a fresh node yet again same thing. unbrowsable

Comment: I've rebuilt the lab and updated the ticket. now it gives **[this error]** (http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6621943/) when I try to browse horizon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turns out that OpenStack  is not compatible with django 1.5
I've removed it and installed 1.4 and everything worked normally.